# Retrieving License and Appliying it to another usb from HASP4 1.33 USB dongle

Tags: export, usb, license-key

my question is the one in the title. I see this dongle is very old, so im pretty sure there must be a way to extract the license that is currently on it and apply it on another usb device,because they are starting to fail and we need to replace them. I would like to apply it to a normal usb drive, or if not, i guess i'll buy specific license dongles, but we need to have our licenses exported.

I've tried to export it with the program included in the Apex software (Which is a Audit Software) with Dphasp, to no avail. The program wont work, as it will just open and close in a few seconds.